# Generate mathematical function out of given values/points

Tags: node.js, math, math.js

I have three points `x0=(x0|y0)`, `x1=(x1|y1)` and `x2=(x2|y2)`.

Now I want to create a mathematical function out of those points.

The target is a function like this: `f(x)=4x^2 + 2x + 6`

What is the best way to do that *in NodeJS*?

Comment: There are many ways to do this depending on what you want. Interpolation, regression, splines... This is a question better asked on MathOverflow.

Comment: If you want your function to exactly pass through the three points, then there is only one solution. You can find it by setting up a system of three equations of the type a*x_i^2+b*x_i+c = y_i and solve it for a,b and c. i ranges from 0 to 2 in your case.

Comment: @Potter: Not mathoverflow, math.stackexchange.com